# Start Rasa Server on a particular IP address

Tags: rasa

I need to run rasa server on a specific ip address so I specified it in endpoints.yml core_endpoint: url: http://10.241.251.172:8081 1

I start rasa server as follows: rasa run --endpoints endpoints.yml -m models --enable-api --cors “*” --debug

It still starts on Starting Rasa server on http://0.0.0.0:5005

How can I force Rasa server to start on a particular IP address. I do not have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: Method using rasa socket io)

**Step 1:**

Go to `credentials.yml` and add the following in that file or uncomment if already

```
socketio:
 user_message_evt: user_uttered
 bot_message_evt: bot_uttered
 session_persistence: false
```

**Step 2:**

run the **rasa** server on your terminal using the following command

```
rasa run -m model --enable-api --cors "*" -p 8081
```

the above command will bind to port 8081 with your IP into the rasa server.

Comment: Where do you specify the IP address ? In endpoints.yml ?

Comment: your Public IP should be mapped with host IP in VM network configuration, no specification is required for any IP in rasa config file only use the above command with the port.

Answer (score 0):

Rasa will automatically get the ip address or domain name of the server/cloud platform where you deploy it.
If you run it locally, it starts on http://0.0.0.0:5005, you can access it on http://localhost:5005
If you want to share your Rasa assistant with users on Internet from your local system, you can use `ngrok` software to make public requests to your localhost.